# How to reference an ACM Certificate using the "Domain name" with the AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

I have a certificate that's a resource in another CloudFormation stack (created by standard CF templates) and I want to reference it by passing the "Domain name" attribute.

The reason I don't want to just use the ARN is because it *could* change if that resource is re-created.

I've looked through the docs and it seems that this kind of thing can be done for other resources using `getAttr` or as a method on the relevant class but neither seem to be options in the case of ACM.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @SebS I haven't but I submitted this issue to them and have decided to go down the SSM params route https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/10792